# Doubts in work done in a control volume

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, work, flow

For a control volume, in a general steady state steady flow process, we can write the generalized equation as-
\begin{align}
\dot{Q}_\text{CV}+\sum\dot{m}_\text{in}\times\theta_\text{in}&=\sum\dot{m}_\text{out}\times\theta_\text{out}+\dot{W}_\text{CV}\\
\dot{Q}_\text{CV}+\sum\dot{m}_\text{in}\times\left(h+\frac{V^2}{2}+gz\right)_\text{in}&=\sum\dot{m}_\text{out}\times\left(h+\frac{V^2}{2}+gz\right)_\text{out}+\dot{W}_\text{CV}
\end{align}

In essence, what is $W_\text{CV}$ here? Does it include flow work also?

If (I guess so) it includes flow work, then why in SSSF devices, like nozzles, do we assume $W_\text{CV}$ to be zero, although there is change in pressure and hence flow work is done?

Comment: Can you use MathJax to format your equations so that they are easier to read?

Comment: How to use it, where to find it?

Comment: [Perhaps here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1)

Comment: @YashkalpSharma You can find on the internet

Comment: Done...now please solve it.

Comment: It doesn't include the flow work.  It is the total work minus the flow work.  It is called the shaft work.

Comment: Chester Miller can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sure I can elaborate.  Get out your thermo book and study the derivation of the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics.  All thermo book explain this very specifically.  They split the total work into the flow work and the shaft work, and include the flow work within the enthalpy term.

Comment: @YashkalpSharma As Chester Miller points out, flow work is in the enthalpy term (along with internal energy) and Wcv is shaft work. The equation you have is for a general control volume. When you apply it to specific devices like turbines, compressors, pumps, condensers, evaporators, nozzles, etc. various terms drop out and the equation is simplified. You need to do some homework to find out how and why.